# Bootstrap 3 - "col" does not follow width of the "row"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I am testing bootstrap3 but my "col" are not following the full width of the "row".
See the picture:
[image: Picture with sample]

I believe that my code is correct, but it dont work.
See:

```
<div class="page-header">Teste Bootstrap</div>
    <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                   col-lg-1
              </div>
                  //Others cols and rows here
          </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using bootstrap 3 with cakePHP framework but don't know if it can disrupt anything.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Obviously the container has the required size, so why not inspect the rows and columns too, and try to figure where things go wrong using the right hand side style explorer?

Comment: The rows are with the size expected. Only the cols dont follow this pattern. I try inspect the elements but dont found anything wrong.

Comment: If you tried that already, then that's information that should be in your question. However even with this info no one here will be able to effeticely help you without having something to reproduce the issue, all people can do is shooting in the dark, which isn't overly helpful. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you shure that there is a problem between `row` and `col` and not between `col` and `container`? Looking at your picture, everything looks fine, do not forget that `row` have negative `margin` for left and right and so are larger than their `container`.

Comment: Hello Holt, when I inspect the .row div your drawn appear full (like 1200px +/-) but it get just 800px. So your columns get 66,65px each. Inspected too the .container div but I don't found any configuration of padding that can cause any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
There a .css file from my framework (cakePHP) that was conflicting with bootstrap, so I disabled it and it works perfectly. To use the cakePHP with bootstrap 3 I will call the bootstrap css file firstly and later call the bake.css and base.css provided by cakePHP.
Thanks Holt and ndm for help and attention!